# why pip reinstalls standard packages listed in install_requires

Tags: python, pip, standard-library, setup.py, install-requires

There is a python package that I need to install using `pip install SomePackage.tar.gz`. In the `setup.py` of this package, a few libraries that are listed under `install_requires` have become part of Python 2.7 Standard Library (like `argparse`).

The problem is that when I install the package on Python 2.7, pip does not realize that, for example, `argparse` is already included in the standard library, and reinstalls it under site-packages.

Is there a way to have pip download and install packages listed under install_requires only if they are not included in the standard library?

Please note that changing `setup.py` is not an option, as the package might be installed under Python 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You say changing `setup.py` is not an option because it might be used under Python 2.6. Change it anyway, with a conditional:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup

install_requires = [
    # ...general modules...
]

if sys.hexversion < 0x02070000:
    install_requires.append('argparse')

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```